# Provisional headers are shown socket io

Tags: express, socket.io, nodes

I am trying to set up socket io for the first time in a production env. I think I am running into some CORS related issues.

Currently the error I am getting is

> Provisional headers are shown

Server side code:

app.js

```
app.io.attach(server);
```

index.js

```
app.io = require('socket.io')({origins: allowed_header});
```

On client side:

```
const socket = io(process.env.SOCKET_ADDRESS);
```

where socket address is `http://localhost:8080` for dev, and `https://websiteName.com:8080` for production

The server uses nginx's default port. **The app works fine when running locally**, but it logs in above error in production env.

Thanks

UPDATE:

I tried to change my local client to connect to remote server. And it works this way as well. It is just my production client now have the following issue:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

UPDATE2:

I could not really solve the problem, so instead I just did the following:

```
origins: ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:4000', '*:*']
```

And it works for now, but I'd like to figure out what is going on. I tried to replace *:* with https://example.com:80, and this didn't work.

Comment: Your client code shows a reference to `process.env.SOCKET_ADDRESS`.  That looks like node.js code.  If so, there is only CORS enforcement from a browser client, not from a node.js client.

Comment: not sure what you mean by that? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: What is your client?  Is it running from a browser?  Or running from a node.js app?  If it's running from a browser, where are you getting `process.env.SOCKET_ADDRESS` from?  That is not something that is supported in a browser.

Comment: browser. Client is just react.

Comment: So, where is `process.env.SOCKET_ADDRESS` coming from in a browser?

Comment: In production, what is the exact URL you're connecting to for socket.io?  And, what is the exactly URL of the web page in the browser URL bar that the Javascript is running from?

Comment: that's not the problem as it works locally on a browser. and I have been using process.env in the .env files

Comment: Please answer my question.  Where does `process.env.SOCKET_ADDRESS` come from in a browser?

Comment: for production server is at https://eflows.ucdavis.edu, same as browse. I am making api calls using that url for server

Comment: it comes from webpack. Webpack uses dotenv and load either .env.prod, or .env.dev into the app

Comment: `  plugins: [
    new DotenvPlugin({
      sample: './.env.default',
      path: './.env.dev',
    }),
`

Comment: If your url host and port are the same for both web page and socket.io connection, then there is no CORS issue.  Or conversely, if you have an actual CORS issue, then those two are NOT the same.  We're flying blind here to debug so all I can do is ask you questions.

Comment: and it doens't really matter, i can just hard code the url of my server, and it still does not work. plus i can just log the process.env variables directly. I dont think that is an issue

Comment: I am not too familiar with nginx, I think my front end is just served as a root, where my node server is on port 8080

Comment: Well, this is something you need to know.  Without seeing detailed code for your server side, there's nothing we do to help with that.  You haven't even mentioned nginx in your question so nothing we know about that.

Comment: yeah, not too sure if that is even related

Comment: Well, your question is far too incomplete about how your setup works for us to have any idea what further questions to even ask.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help with all the CORS error

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

Docs [CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)